Implicit join is working but explicit join is not working
We have to find all dates Id with higher temperature compare to its previous dates.
id.   Recorddate.   Temprature 
  1.    2015-01-01.   10
  2.    2015-01-02.   25

The output should be
Id
 2

During implicit join I am getting results :
Select w1.id 
from weather w1 
inner join weather w2 
where Datediff(w1.recorddate,w2.recorddate) = 1 
      and w1.temprature = w2.Temprature

While explicit join I am not getting any result
Select w1.id 
from weather w1 
inner join weather w2 on w1.id = w2.id 
where Datediff(w1.recorddate,w2.recorddate) = 1 
     and w1.temprature = w2.Temprature

Can you please help me

In 1st query your join is CROSS JOIN. There is no w1.id = w2.id condition which is present in 2nd table. PS. "Implicit join" is comma-style join, i.e. .. FROM weather w1, weather w2 ...

w1.id = w2.id condition is obviousy incorrect if id is PK - you search for the row which have different dates which is obviously impossible.
